# How do I modulo an input by two to check if the number is even or odd?

Tags: python

How do I modulo an input by two to check if the number is even or odd?
**here is my code**

```
num = input("Enter a number: ")
   mod = num % 2
   if mod > 0:
     print("You picked an odd number.")
   else:
      print("You picked an even number.")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take the `int` value of the input. `int(input("Enter a number: "))`

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the `input` to an `int`eger like below:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
mod = num % 2
if mod > 0:
    print("You picked an odd number.")
else:
    print("You picked an even number.")
```

`%` is for string formatting for strings, for integers it's for modulo.

Answer (score 0):

There is no meaning to test `num%2>0`. `num % 2` is the remainder of the integer division of `num` by `2`. `num` is even if and only if this remainder equals 0. So the predicate `is_even(n)` corresponds to `num % 2==0`.

Your code becomes :

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
   if  num % 2==0:
      print("You picked an even number.")
   else:
      print("You picked an odd number.")
```

You should consider defining a function and then call it like this:

```py
def is_even(n):
    return n%2==0

n = int(input("Enter a number:"))
if is_even(n): print("You picked an even number")
else: print("You picked an odd number")
```

Comment: Correction: `num %2 == 0` should print `even`